# how to autoplay audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to autoplay audio, when the page is loaded?

I have tried put autoplay in the audio tag, and it didn't work.

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay>
  <source src="audio/dark-tense-piano-drone.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

and I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#audio").get(0).play(); 
  $('#audio').prop("volume", 0.2);
}
```

then it didn't work.

Is there any other idea to autoplay audio, when the page is loaded?

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: I have tried with my friend computer and it still didn't work

Comment: But have you checked the browser console to see if you have any errors showing?? For Google Chrome you can press **CTRL** + **Shift** & **J**

Comment: your code works unless the src is wrong or missing from source

Comment: Note that some users may hate you. Also, possibly relevant: MDN's [Autoplay guide for media and Web Audio APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide). Are you sure you satisfy preconditions for autoplay to be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Try with controls

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't support audio.

Try:

```
    <audio id="audio" autoplay>
    <source src="audio/dark-tense-piano-drone.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Also check the console to see if file is available.